# Hypothetical unknown cipher - security in obscurity?

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, brute-force-attack

I'm curious what would happen in the following scenario:

Suppose an attacker gets a hold of a cipher-text of sufficiently large length. And suppose he has the means to verify a successful decryption.
But the attacker has no clue what cipher is used and assumes it's unbreakable with anything but brute-force whatever it is.
He also assumes it's a block cipher. (Thus, whatever operations the cipher performs are repeated over each block.)

1. Suppose he knows the block is of length 128bit. How long (what is the complexity) will it take him to brute-force all possible operations that can be performed?
2. What if it's XTS and the attacker doesn't know anything about any standards?

I guess this is just to contrast the security in obscurity argument, but I'm also interested in the complexity numbers.

Also, what would happen if you modify AES in some way, like adding some extra rounds or an extra operation, something simple. And make it such that the change is NOT hard-coded into the algorithm but is instead loaded as a module/script as PART of the key to access the encrypted data? How much complexity would that add to someone trying to get your plain-text if he doesn't even know precisely what algorithm is used.

Comment: Your premises are implausible in practice.  What if an alien bought a pig at the market, and the pig the alien picked just happened to be able to fly?  Hey, it could happen....

Comment: D.W. your comment is not very helpful. Lets assume for now that "alien" can be replaced with "attacker that does not know the algorithm/details of encryption used". That might be common for an attacker if the protocol is new/unknown/uncommon. I think these are some interesting questions regardless and deserve an answer.

Comment: In this situation, the workload shifts from reverse engineering the algorithm from only ciphertext to acquisition of algorithm details, which would have a substantially lower workload. There are too many permutations to deal with, as the situation has occurred in our history many times, and it only falls with details of the implementation.

Comment: Your question reads like a [Choose Your Own Adventure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choose_Your_Own_Adventure) book.  They're valid questions - but I suggest you break them up into smaller, more answerable questions.  I also suggest you read on up [Kerckhoffs's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs's_principle).

Comment: 128 bit block, doesn't this mean there are 2^128 possible combinations and therefore 2^128 possible operations?

Comment: You should never consider a cipher algorithm as perfectly secret. The algorithm was a human invention. While some human inventions are very strange, they might be more repeatable than you might think. Moreover, it is very hard to calculate its "entropy". Well, we might try to solve it by constructing a tweakable algorithm: you add some random data to generate an algorithm automatically. Wait, the random data works at best as a key for the algorithm…

Comment: The generic 128b block encryption function is a bijection from $2^{128}$ values to $2^{128}$ values, thus there are $2^{128}!$ such functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An unknown block-cipher with an $n$-bit block length can just be viewed as an arbitrary permutation of size $2^n$. Assuming you have the means to verify a correct decryption, you can just try each of every $2^n!$ possible permutations.

Naturally, if your ciphertext consists of fewer than $2^n$ distinct block values then you can omit permutations which result in previously-tried plaintexts.

An extreme example of this would be a ciphertext consisting of one block of $n$ bits which would need only a maximum of $2^n-1$ decryptions to be tested. This is of course significantly less than $2^n!$

Comment: Yeah, $2^n!$ is *huge* for any nontrivial $n$. I suppose you might justify it by saying they're aliens or whatever. The first natural $k$ such that $k! > 2^{128}$ is $k=35$, and $35 \ll 2^{35} \ll 2^{128}$, for an idea of the scale of numbers you're dealing with.

Comment: And for $n = 128$, the factorial itself has more than $10^{40}$ _digits_. (See [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%5E128)!)).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the last part of the question, this approach is called "key-dependent transformations", or ["key-dependent S-boxes"](http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/round2/comments/20000515-smurphy.pdf) if we speak about smaller blocks that are key-dependent.

While this approach complicates the attacker's life in general, it might actually weaken the construction as the resulting operation may be weak or strong depending on the key. It is hard to generate a family of transformations, indexed by the key, that are equally good. This approach has been tried in 1980-90s, but eventually a simple xor of the key into the cipher's state proved the best.